# Найти хотя-бы одно совпадение строки со списком, как можно реализовать?

Tags: python

Есть input, есть "база" с именами и возрастом. Нужно при вводе юзернейма пройтись по всем именам в базе и если нет совпадений, выдать одно сообщение, если есть, то другое. Серьезно, бьюсь несколько дней, так и не понял ( я дурачог )

```
     lst=[
        ("ник1", 22),
        ("ник2", 22),
        ("ник3", 14),
        ("ник4", 53),
        ("ник5", 43),
    ]

us = input("ник: ")
```

Это такое начало кода. Я решил выписать в отдельный файл это, чтобы было проще..

Comment: Всё таки для данной задачи лучше использовать не список, а словарь. Тогда и искать ничего специально не надо.

Comment: Да, наверное, но я упростил задачу и сделал ее маленький аналог. В полном размере все по другому ( уже задавал вопрос по полной, но не ответили )

Answer (score 2):

Ну или так для проверки по всему списку сразу:

```
if us in [x[0] for x in lst]:
     print(f"{us} найден в списке")
else:
     print(f"{us} не найден")
```

Comment: Спасиба) До такого кода я не могу додуматься...

Answer (score 1):

```
for user in lst:
    if user[0] == us: print("Это то")
    else: print("Это не то")
```

Comment: И почему я такой тупой...
Но если нет, то "Это не то" пишется несколько раз..
А также, если ник есть, то пишется "это не то" до тех пор, пока не наткнется на совпадение, а потом снова пишет "это не то")